# Does this seem like a reasonable sign-up flow in terms of how the authorization provider relates to the retention of user data within the database?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, authentication, data-modeling

I only wish to employ Auth0 as my application's API provider but otherwise
would prefer to maintain any and all data about my users within my application's own database, thus, as one might well surmise, my application's database contains a `users` table along with several related tables. So, once a user signs up for my app, I'd need to create records for that user within the database. Then, once the user logs in via Auth0, I'd like to retrieve that user's data via information contained within the access token. (The field that presents itself as most useful for this purpose is "azp," or "authorized party.")

I'm thinking that, once the user signs up, as part of the effort to create the relevant records within the database, I'd save the "authorized party" value to a field on the `users` table. (Which field I cannot say, but, for now, this seems as sound a plan as any.) Then, when the user logs in via the Auth0 hosted API, I would retrieve their record from the database via the "authorized party" value.

Does this sound like a reasonable/sound plan? This is my first time building a full-on application from scratch, and, well, this particular detail has me scratching my head.

Comment: Did you ever get any input on this? I'm transitioning from RoR and Devise where it was all managed within my database so also stumped by how best to do this!